# How to call a context help by A-link (A-keyword) on application for Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, help-system

How to call a context help by A-link (A-keyword) on application for Delphi XE2?

Comment: This has nothing to do with help not working in Delphi, as you're not using Delphi's support for help. You're using the `IHTMLHelpTester` interface directly. You also provide no information about the OS you're using, and your graphics are not in English (but you provided no translation of what's being displayed in the right pane of the image for what's not working or any error information). It's pretty hard to explain what might be wrong. :-)

Comment: Aren't you meant to call `Application.HelpKeyword(TheKeyword)`?

Comment: The question was simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is this function:

```
procedure ShowHelpALink(const HelpFile, ALink: string);
var
  Link: THH_AKLink;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@Link, SizeOf(Link));
  Link.cbStruct := SizeOf(Link);
  Link.pszKeywords := PChar(AnsiString(ALink));
  Link.fIndexOnFail := True;
  HtmlHelp(GetDesktopWindow, HelpFile, HH_ALINK_LOOKUP, DWORD_PTR(@Link));
end;
```

For some reason `HtmlHelp` interprets the strings in the `THH_AKLink` record as ANSI strings. I cannot find any documentation on this. I suspect it is simply a bug in the HtmlHelp file library. I think that the strings that you pass in `THH_AKLink` must be ANSI strings.

Comment: It calls standard lookup - not by A-links for me:(( Why does it happen?

Comment: Also there is another issue now. When I close help window application's form closes too. Something strange.

Comment: And the third issue. This code shows help only on F1. If I just execute it - nothing happens.

Comment: This code is unrelated to F1. Are you running this code in a vanilla app? Or did you try to splice it into your existing app? Start off with a vanilla app. That contains nothing but this code and a call to it.

Comment: I see no problems with help window closing app window. Again, try in a vanilla app. Do you understand what the code in the answer does? Did you read the documentation of `HH_ALINK_LOOKUP` on MSDN? Please don't treat an SO answer as a black box.

Comment: The corrent code is `Application.HelpFile` instead `HelpFile`. But I can't cancel default handler for F1 key - even I have TAction with F1 shortcut. Help opens with keyword instead A-link on F1 key.